# Magento 2 how to disable Page Cache programmatically?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I need to disable Page Cache so it does not keep old data on the page.

When I dIsable it from admin panel it works, but then it gets backs to enabled by no reason.

Is there a way I can keep it disabled like the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin setting you are adding should stay disabled if you set it like that in a vanilla Magento installation. I am assuming you have some customizations in place, maybe some environment specifics (setups, builds, etc), so I would check those first to isolate which process re-enables FPC.

Whether you disable if from the GUI or programmatically, if there's something somewhere which says FPC should be enabled, it would definitely overwrite your programmatic FPC disabling.

Comment: do you think it could be because of some extra modules? the only module that I have installed besides mine is Stripe, and my module does not do anything with the cache. Or if I run this commands php bin/magento cache:clean and cache:flush could be the problem?

Comment: running cache clearing or flushing commands won't re-enable the FPC. i am still thinking of a customization somewhere or an additional process in a pipeline or a setup.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I think I can do that research now

Comment: no problem, anytime!